# When use with after(), slidedown function does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've tried many way to sliding down a new element created with after()  using examples I found on internet but it does not work.

I tried these possibilities without success
with the following code ,  **the element appears quickly without slidedown effect**

```
$this.after("<p id='comment' style='display:none'>" + data + "</p>");
$("#comment").slideDown(2000);
```

**with the following code, the element is not displayed**

```
$(this).after("<div id='comment' style='display:none'>" + data + "</p>", function(){
                            $("#comment").slideDown().css('display', 'inline');
                        });
```

**with the following code, the element is not displayed**

```
$(this).after("<div id='comment' >" + data + "</p>", function(){
                            $("#comment").slideDown(2000);
                        });
```

**Maybe,  I should clarify that the code is within ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $("#button<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").click(function(e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create'); ?>",
                    success: function(data) {

                       $this.after("<p id='comment' style='display:none'>" + data + "</p>");
                       $("#comment").slideDown(2000);
}
                });
            });

        });
    });
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) dies not have a callback method

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6uwyD/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Create a custom function to trigger slideDown, call it in your ajax call success.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
        function mySlideFn(){
           $("#comment").slideDown(2000);
        }
            $("#button<?php echo $data['id']; ?>").click(function(e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create'); ?>",
                    success: function(data) {

                       $this.after("<p id='comment' style='display:none'>" + data + "</p>");
                       mySlideFn();
            }
                });
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: I added clarification in my post  @Manoj

Comment: Your ajax call is not completing successfully, might be because of wrong url or the page you are calling is not there.Check if your url is correct or not

Comment: yes the ajax complete successfully because in the first code example, the result is displayed

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work fine:

```
$(this).after('<p class="comment" style="display: none;">A comment</p>');
$('.comment').slideDown(2000);
```

Perhaps in your first example you're not referencing `$(this)` properly. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQwRz/)

Comment: @rinkattendant6  I added clarification in my post